# PHP Syntax for webpage radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql

Currently I have the following table in my database

```
|AnswerID|QuestionID|AnswerText|
|21|2|User|
|22|2|Admin|
|23|2|Guest|
|24|2|User2|
```

and written the following php script

```
$questionID=0;
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
echo $list['QuestionID'] . ":" . $list['QuestionText'] . "<br/>";  
$questionID=$list['QuestionID'];
}
$optionsquery="SELECT AnswerText,AnswerID FROM Options Where QuestionID=".$questionID;
$optionsresult=mysql_query($optionsquery) or die ('Query failed:'. mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($optionsresult))
{
  'Display the multiple choices 
   associating the AnswerID with the appropriate AnswerText.' 

   E.g. echo "<input type='radio' name='QuestionID'     
              value='AnswerID'/>" 
              corresponding AnswerText given the AnswerID;

   E.g for the first radio button:

   echo "<input type='radio' name='2' value='21'/> User;

}
```

Could I get help with the PHP syntax for the radio buttons?

Comment: There is no "php syntax" for radio buttons. There is only PHP code which generates text that happens to be html which results in a radio button being displayed. There's no difference between PHP doing a database query to output a number than PHP doing a database query to fill something into a radio button.

Comment: Okie maybe the question is phrased wrongly, so the question is how to populate the radio buttons with the values from my database as mentioned in the above ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
echo "<input type='radio' id='radio-" . $row["QuestionID"] . "-" . $row["AnswerID"] . "' name='" . $row["QuestionID"] . "' value='" . $row["AnswerID"] . "' /> <label for='radio-" . $row["QuestionID"] . "-" . $row["AnswerID"] . "'>" . $row["AnswerText"] ."</label><br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but now how can I check/determine if the selected radio button option corresponds to the respective AnswerID ? This is essential because I plan to record the selected AnswerID for each of the respective question to tabulate the results of the quiz.

Comment: If you are using jquery then $("input[name='InsertQuestionIDHere']:checked").val() will return the AnswerID corresponding to the checked answer

Comment: Honestly I am confused of how and where to put ur recommend code snippet into my form. Could you further elaborate or provide links to that tutorial ? Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: Add this once at the top of the PHP file: `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>function GetAnswer(questionID) {$(\"input[name='\" + questionID.toString() + \"']:checked\").val()}</script>";`. Then all you have to do to find out the results for a question is use the following javascript: `question2answer = GetAnswer(2);`